# Using iScroll prevents the keyboard from showing on my device

Tags: android, iphone, mobile-webkit, iscroll4, webkit-transform

I am using iScroll for providing iPhone style scrolling. But, when clicking on the textboxes, the keyboard does not show up.

While trying to find the possible cause, I found that removing the `iScroll` script, makes it work normal, but in that case I miss the scrolling functionality.

Is this a bug in iScroll. If yes, is there a tested work-around? Or is there any alternative for iScroll?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the error. The problem was with the CSS.

I thought may be the CSS is somehow creating the problem. I concluded this on the basis that when I commented the CSS for `wrapper` and `scroller`, the keyboard showed up... but keeping them, the keyboard didn't work. I was using `bottom: 0px;`, which seemed to be somehow preventing the keyboard from showing.

Removing `bottom: 0px;` solved my problem.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 4):

At least in iScroll 4, you can add this code to enable clicking of input fields. See the demo on Form-fields in the examples folder.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myScroll;
function loaded() {
    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
        useTransform: false,
        onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) {
            var target = e.target;
            while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;

            if (target.tagName != 'SELECT' && target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA')
                e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);

</script>
```

Comment: I noticed the solution above makes performance very bad on a page with medium or very complex html. I'm yet to find a solution, but will try what the OP suggested below.

Comment: Disabling the CSS didn't solve it, it just makes it impossible to scroll at all. So the problem is definitely in iScroll. Here's a thread about it: http://code.google.com/p/iscroll-js/issues/detail?id=17

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code to _start in iScroll 4.2 to solve this problem:

```
  if (e && e.target && e.target.tagName) {
    var bFocusField = ('|INPUT|TEXTAREA|BUTTON|SELECT|'
                         .indexOf('|' + e.target.tagName + '|') >= 0);
    if (bFocusField || that.focusField) {
      if (bFocusField) {
        that.focusField = e.target;
      } else {
        that.focusField.blur();
        that.focusField = null;
      }
      e.defaultPrevented = false;
      e.returnValue = true;
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Code is inserted below the initialization part of the function (that.moved = false; ... that.dirY = 0;).

Tested it on iPad 1 (iOS 5.1) and iPad 3 (iOS 6). The onscreen keyboard does not seem to interfere with iScroll (I do an iScroll.refresh() every 5 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this solution is optimal
Tweak the code in iscroll.js, ( as follows )

```
onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) { 
                //e.preventDefault();
                if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "select" || e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input' || e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'textarea'){             
                    return;
                    } 
            },
```